# How to make my android calculator working

Tags: java, android

I am making a basic calculator for Android in Java.  I am stuck in one final step where it must add the input with the previous input. Have a look at the code:

```
    public void displayValue(){

    String mything = display.getText().toString();
    input = Integer.parseInt(mything);

}
public void number1(View view){
    if (input == 0){display.setText("");}

    display.append(Integer.toString(1));
    displayValue();

}
public void number2(View view){
    if (input == 0){display.setText("");}

    display.append(Integer.toString(2));
    displayValue();

}
public void plus(View view){
    displayValue();            //result= 0
    result = result + input;   //result= input
    input = 0;                 //input=0

    //in this step input becomes 0 to let the user enter new number input but this 
    //input never add the old result and the equal shows the old result.
}
public void equal(View view){
    displayValue();
    display.setText(Integer.toString(result));

}
```

I noticed that if I add a line in equal method and add the result to input I get the correct answer but that's not gonna be helpful as there will be minus button too.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe the problem a little better like what result you are getting where and what is the expected result?

Comment: @codeMagic OK sure. As it is a calculator. the user press a few numbers. the 'displayValue' method change it to int saved in 'input' and when the user press the plus or minus button, it save the entered number in 'result' variable. Then input becomes 0 again and user enter the other side of the calculation. And then presses the equal sign to get the result. So value that saved in result minuses or adds to the second input and show the result in the screen. This is how it suppose to work. But my problem is, it never get the chance to calculate the result with second input.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely hard to tell because you don't include full code, which would be helpful, but could it be because you call `displayValue();` in some places before doing the math? Specifically in the `plus` method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I came up with a solution.
As the only option for calculation of result and new input is in equal method (because logically when user press the equal button, so wants to ends the equation), so I added two boolean values for each minus and plus calculation. Then I added both calculation for adding or minus 2 values.
Then when the user inter first part of the calculation and then hit plus sign, the boolean value of plus becomes true and after entering new input and hitting the equal sign, it does the true part of the calculation. Well it is a bit hard to explain but i guess by looking at the code you would get what I mean.

```
boolean whenMinus = false;
boolean whenPlus = false;

public void plus(View view){
    displayValue();
    result = input;
    input = 0;
    whenPlus = true;
}
public void minus(View view){
    displayValue();
    result = input;
    input = 0;
    whenMinus = true;
}
public void equal(View view){
    if (whenPlus == true){result = result + input; whenPlus = false;}
    if (whenMinus == true){result = result - input; whenMinus = false;}

    display.setText(Integer.toString(result));

}
```

I am not sure if it is the correct way of making this calculator. But I fixed my problem anyway.  It would be great to comment me and let me know if it is the standard way or its kinda hacking. I am not a pro anyway.